Нужнa ли запятая в этом предложении?
Она была достаточно умна, чтобы узнать ответ и произнести его(,) и даже сообщить, где именно ошибся этот человек.
Как мне кажется, в придаточном предложении однородными сказуемыми являются только слова "узнать" и "произнести". Но тогда не понятно, какой член предложения глагол "сообщить". Не очень понимаю, как это объяснить.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, ставится ли запятая на месте пропуска? Как правильно в данном предложении определить грамматическую основу и однородные члены?

Правильно:
Она была достаточно умна, чтобы узнать ответ и произнести его и даже сообщить, где именно ошибся этот человек.
Примечание. Постановка запятой возможна только в авторском варианте, тогда второй союз И — присоединительный. Для обозначения пояснительного значення можно использовать союз А ТАКЖЕ.
Пояснение

Это СПП, три предиктивные основы, последовательное подчинение придаточных. Первое придаточное со значение степени признака и цели (достаточно умна, чтобы).  Второе придаточное изъяснительное: сообщить (что?) где именно ошибся этот человек; ГДЕ — союзное слово.

Первое придаточное односоставное, инфинитивное, осложнено тремя однородными сказуемыми. Третье сказуемое модифицировано усилительное частицей ДАЖЕ.  Два первых сказуемых тесно связаны по смыслу,  а третье сказуемое соединено  с ними вторым союзом И. Розенталь, пункт 8

Формант И ДАЖЕ в общем случае  имеет соединительное значение,  но при осложненном синтаксисе присоединительное значение нельзя исключать. Этот вопрос обсуждался на форуме, но там высказаны только предположения, даже подходящих примеров из литературы нет (см. Карту слов).


